# SharePoint 2010 Content Organizer Rule Issue

Tags: records-center

I am facing problem with the content organizer processing and in dropoff library. In my scenario what is required is: when a user upload a document in Record center the document should go Drop off library and from there as per the content organizer rule defined should move to the Record center library (as per the Record Center functionality).

But what I am getting is whenever any user uploads document the document remains in dropoff library and a copy gets moved inside Record center as well, also it sends the mail for "Additional Infomation required" to the admins. Not sure about this why dropoff behaving this way? If it is not saving the complete data then hows it moving a copy to Record Center library? Anyone faced such issue please help me.. and in drop off library when I press edit document property button and press save it again moves the document to Record Center library with some random words addition in the document title. :(

Again there is a query when in edit properties page of Drop off library it is not asking to enter any required field why the system generating "Additional Information Required" mails every time a new document is uploaded?

Answer (score 1):

The Drop Off library serves as the location where  Documents to which rules cannot be matched are moved into, which also generates email messages to Content Stewart, according to your settings (digest or immediate). You would probably need to check your rules, if by any chance you do not have a rule that plays like a "catch-all", also it is recomanded that you do create your own Content types and do not use the Default Document Content type as this will definitely be more dificult to differentiate and could generate mentioned behavior.

Also check if you do not have by any chance a workflow (e.g. IM policies rules in the Records Center libraries by default enabled).

Comment: Hi Marius, I am having my own content type attached to the drop off library and on target document library. Also I cross checked the rules again they seems to be fine, as they are moving the documents if i edit the document property from dropoff library and then press the save button without modifying any of the fields value. I am facing weird behavior of dropoff library as on the first go it is making a copy of the submitted document and moving to final location and the another copy on dropoff library whereas it gives the message to the user uploading document as "Moved to drop off library".

Comment: Have you by any chance configured the CO to redirect everything to Drop Off? This also means that as soon as you upload it already goes there! Did you also configured any of the rules to send documents to Drop Off? if that is the case a circular reference is created. You should not create rules that send content to Drop-Off.

Comment: Hi Maurius, I don't have any rule tht redirect documents to drop off library.

Answer (score 0):

The random letters being added is set in the Content Organizer rules under the Site Settings. Go there and decide if you want it to add those letters when you have a duplicate file, or if you want it to make a new version of the existing file. There is also a choice there about whether or not to send files to the Drop Off Library first.  Pick Yes or No. Those choices should all be set up before you allow people to start uploading files. :) Then go to the Organizer Rules link (Again Site Settings), and put in your Content Type, and your conditions.